# How to split children in object to separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This might be an odd question, but I'm working on a project and can't seem to figure this one out. I need to be able to take a Javascript Object like this:

```
{
    field1: {
        field2: {
            field3: "value 1",
            field4: "value 2"
        }
    }
}
```

And take any field that has more than one key, and split the results into separate arrays like this:

```
[
    {
        field1: {
            field2: {
                field3: "value 1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        field1: {
            field2: {
                field4: "value 2"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I've tried building a few recursive functions that will traverse the object structure, and anytime a `value` is of type `object` and has more than one key, I try to copy the object and give each "child" it's own parent structure. I don't know if this makes much sense but I've been stuck on this for a while and feel like I'm maybe just overlooking something simple that can get this job done.

I appreciate any input. Thank you!

Comment: do you mean *any* object with more than one property should spawn enough objects to flatten? or only at a specific level.

Comment: @pilchard Yeah it should be any object an any level deep. So theoretically, instead of `field4` containing a String, it could contain another object with multiple keys that would also need to be flattened. This is where I'm getting pretty stumped.

Comment: Will there only ever be one object in the original tree with multiple keys?

Comment: @AndrewParks no, there could potentially be multiple objects with multiple keys. It feels like it could get pretty messy pretty fast haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick sample on your original input.

But more test cases with valid output would be needed to verify. (It definitely goes off the rails quickly)

```js
const input = {
  field1: {
    field2: {
      field3: "value 1",
      field4: "value 2"
    }
  }
};

function recursivelyFlatten(obj) {
  const result = [];

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (v && typeof v === 'object' && Object.entries(v).length) {
      for (const o of recursivelyFlatten(v)) {
        result.push({ [k]: o });
      }
    }
    else {
      result.push({ [k]: v });
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(recursivelyFlatten(input));
```

Further samples:

```js
function recursivelyFlatten(obj) { const result = []; for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) { if (v && typeof v === 'object' && Object.entries(v).length) { for (const o of recursivelyFlatten(v)) { result.push({ [k]: o }); } } else { result.push({ [k]: v }); } } return result; }

// Input 1
const input1 = {
  field1: {
    field2: {
      field3: "value 1",
      field4: "value 2"
    }
  },
  field5: {
    field6: {
      field7: "value 3"
    },
    field8: {
      field9: "value 4"
    }
  }
};

console.log(recursivelyFlatten(input1));

// Input 2
const input2 = {
  field1: {
    field2: {
      field3: {
        f3_1: 'v3_1',
        f3_2: 'v3_2',
      },
      field4: "value 2"
    }
  }
};

console.log(recursivelyFlatten(input2));
```

Comment: Wow this is really clever. Thank you so much, this is WAYYY simpler that whatever garbage I've been writing. You are awesome, thank you.

Comment: Be sure to test it, but I think it points in the right direction.

Comment: I've been testing it, this is a much better solution that what I had been attempting, I really appreciate it. I have much to learn. Thank you.